# Where do I start to debug a network problem?

Tags: network

I am unable to ping outside of my mac from the Terminal, and yet the internet connection (as seen from Safari) is otherwise just fine.

Where do I start to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac is probably behind a proxy.  This article explains how to [configure proxy settings](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8760.html) on your Mac.  If you are behind a proxy, then you probably will not be able to get `ping` to work.

Otherwise, the first step to troubleshooting a connectivity issue when Safari is working is to use `traceroute` to some well-maintained destination.  I typically use google.com.

```
traceroute google.com
```

If you get the error `unknown host google.com` then you have a DNS problem.  Otherwise `traceroute` should provide you with information that helps you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: In this case specifying the host ('traceroute -p port host') is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with a similar issue you its possible that something is blocking your ping requests. You should try to restart your modem and router (power cycle). This worked in my scenario.